# write Oracle Function that checks if record exists if not merge it into same table

Tags: oracle, function, merge

Trying to efficiently check if record exists based on reference_no if it does return its ID, if not insert it and return a new ID.

Maybe a MERGE is not the way to go?

can't figure out the syntax !

```
 create or replace FUNCTION   get_note_history_id(   
     p_owner_id VARCHAR2,    --to insert to the note history table 
     p_open_date DATE,    --to insert to the note history table
     p_note_log CLOB,    --to insert to the note history table
     p_collection_id VARCHAR2,  --not to break the previous code
     p_reference_no NUMBER --correlates to the notice (date) sent)
 )


 return VARCHAR2 is 
 v_note_history_id NUMBER

 MERGE INTO NOTE_HISTORY n
 USING(

  select NOTE_HISTORY_ID
  from NOTE_HISTORY
  where p_reference_no = n.notice_reference_no
  ) h

 WHEN MATCHED THEN
    v_note_history_id := h.NOTE_HISTORY_ID;

 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

    INSERT INTO NOTE_HISTORY (create_user_id,create_date,note,collection_id,notice_reference_no)
    VALUES (p_owner_id,p_open_date,p_note_log,p_collection_id,p_reference_no) returning NOTE_HISTORY_ID into v_note_history_id;

 RETURN v_note_history_id;


 END get_note_history_id;
```

Comment: Merge is a SQL DML statement that combines update and insert. Not a PL/SQL flow of control statement that can conditionally execute arbitrary PL/SQL statements. The returning clause is valid for insert, but not the insert arm of a merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach has a couple of problems. MERGE is pure a SQL construct so we can't include PL/SQL code in it. Also, MERGE doesn't support RETURNING clause  (which is annoying).

All of which means you need to implement an old fashioned UPSERT. You can try either an UPDATE and switch to an INSERT on `no_data_found` or lead with the INSERT and switch to an UPDATE on `dup_val_on_index`. The decision should be based on the prevalent path: if you're expecting mainly matches go for UPDATE first,  mainly misses go for INSERT. If you don't have a unique constraint on `notice_reference_no` (tsk, tsk) you need to use UPDATE regardless.

Although as you're not actually updating anything on the WHEN MATCHED arm a simple lookup will suffice:

```
create or replace FUNCTION   get_note_history_id(   
     p_owner_id VARCHAR2,    --to insert to the note history table 
     p_open_date DATE,    --to insert to the note history table
     p_note_log CLOB,    --to insert to the note history table
     p_collection_id VARCHAR2,  --not to break the previous code
     p_reference_no NUMBER --correlates to the notice (date) sent)
 )
is 
    v_note_history_id number;
begin
  begin
     select n.note_history_id
     into v_note_history_id
     from NOTE_HISTORY n
     where n.notice_reference_no = p_reference_no ;
  exception
     WHEN no_data_found THEN
        INSERT INTO NOTE_HISTORY (create_user_id,create_date,note,collection_id,notice_reference_no)
        VALUES (p_owner_id,p_open_date,p_note_log,p_collection_id,p_reference_no) 
        returning NOTE_HISTORY_ID into v_note_history_id;
    end; 
    return v_note_history_id;
end;
/
```

As a rule I dislike the use of the Exception block to handle what is actually normal business processing, but other approaches are even more inelegant.